# Suppose |$A$| = |$B$| and let $f: A \to B$ be a surjective function. Can we/ should we define the ratio of size of set $A$ : set $B$ wrt function $f$?

Tags: set-theory, order-theory, cardinals

I've not seen this idea anywhere before, but I'm not a set theory buff either.

Let $A$ and $B$ be sets with the same cardinality and let $f: A \to B$ be a surjective function. Suppose, for every $y \in B$, there are exactly $n \in \mathbb{N}$ members of $A$ such that $f$ maps these members of $A$ to $y$.

Then define the Rubinson-ratio of the size of set $A$ : set $B$ wrt function $f$ to be $n:1$.

...and perhaps we may say, wrt function $f$, $A$ is $n$ times Rubinson-larger than $B$.

We can probably extend this idea in a few ways, but let's leave it as is for now.

Is this a known idea in set theory? Else, may I claim the name for it?

Comment: Isn't $n=1$ for all $y\in B$ for surjective $f$? And why should $n$ be uniform for all $y$ even if $f$ were to be not surjective?

Comment: If $A$ and $B$ are infinite, then $f$ could be surjective without being injective.

Comment: For example, define  $f: \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ by $f(1)=1, f(2)=1, f(3)=2, f(4)=2, f(5)=3, f(6)=3, f(7)=4,f(8)=4, etc.$ This is an example of $n=2$. "And why should n be uniform for all y even if f were to be not surjective?" I never said anything about non-surjective functions.

Comment: Scrap my earlier comment, I was only considering the finite case. $n$ may be non-uniform. Or are you restricting yourself to the class of surjections with uniform $n$ only?

Comment: Let's restrict to uniform only for now. Like I say in the question, this idea can be extended in many ways and the way I present it is the simplest way I could think to start the idea off.

Comment: This is akin to an index of, for example, a subgroup in a group, where in that case the morphism $f$ is the natural projection (this is even working when the index is infinite). This shows up in other places as well where all the fibres of $f$ have the same size (e.g. something like a vector bundle where the fibres of the projection are all vector spaces of the same dimension).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This idea comes up frequently in combinatorics. It is called a **$k$-to-$1$ correspondence**. It allows you to relate the cardinality of the domain and range via the $k$ factor, which can allow for counting one of the sets more conveniently than it would otherwise be possible directly. Also, I don't think that people can "claim" names like that. One can be the first discoverer, but names must be accepted by the relevant community. On a more humorous note, see [Stigler's law of eponomy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stigler%27s_law_of_eponymy).

As requested by the OP in the comments, [here is a link](https://www.cs.colostate.edu/%7Ecs220/spring19/slides/16_bijection_rule.pdf) to a reference that uses this term in the finite setting. (However, a k-to-1 correspondence is also applicable to an infinite setting where the two sets $A$ and $B$ share the same cardinality $\aleph_i$)

Comment: Haha that's a brilliant answer!

Comment: Although is k-to-1 correspondence usually applied to finite sets only, or infinite sets like my question asks? I guess there's some sort of infinite combinatorics that uses integration that I'm not yet aware of...

Comment: @AdamRubinson I have personally seen it only in the finite combinatorial setting. It seems like one would not meet much resistance if one used the same term in an infinite setting, but it is possible that a different name exists or does not exist in the general case.

Comment: https://www.cs.colostate.edu/~cs220/spring19/slides/16_bijection_rule.pdf
"Let $X$ and $Y$ be finite sets. A function $f:X→Y$ is a k-to-1
correspondence if for every $y ∈ Y$, there are exactly $k$
different $x ∈ X$ such that $f(x) = y$". Let's remove the word "finite" and accept Favst's answer. In fact, Favst, please add this link and quote to your answer if you don't mind.

Comment: @AdamRubinson done, it has been added to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

let's talk about the Rubinson ratio!

First of all, just to answer your question directly, I have never heard of a name for this concept in the context of infinite sets, although there are a few related concepts that I'll get into shortly.

But I've also never seen this concept used (other than as a part of the related concepts). There's an saying that "[a mathematical object is what it does](https://sites.math.rutgers.edu/%7Ezeilberg/Opinion50.html)." What does this concept do? What sorts of proofs can we construct with it? You can call this the "Rubinson ratio," and you can say that that's the name of it, but until and unless you do something with it, it's not really yours. The person who gets to name a concept generally isn't the first person who comes up with it, but the first person to do something with it.

In my (albeit limited) encounters with set theory, it's been very rare that I'm using a function like you describe, between two sets of equal cardinality, where the size of the preimage of each element in the range is equal. However, I think you're essentially trying to define a way to think about the "size" of one infinite set compared to another, and in that case we do have a few examples:

First, if we have a subset $A\subseteq\mathbb{N}$ of the natural numbers, we can define the [Natural density](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_density) of $A$ as follows: First, we define $f_A(n)=\big|A\cap \mathbb{N}^{\leq n}\big|$ be the number of elements of $A$ that are $\leq n$. Then the natural density $d(A)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{f_A(n)}n$. This works similarly to how you would expect: the density of the even numbers is $\frac12$, as is the density of the odd numbers. The density of the multiples of $3$ is $\frac13$, etc. The primes, the squares, and all finite sets have natural density $0$.

There's also a related concept in group theory: If we have a group $G$ and a subgroup $H$, then we can define $[G:H]$ (read as "G over H") to be the number of left cosets of $H$ in $G$. When $G$ and $H$ are finite, $[G:H]=\frac{|G|}{|H|}$. We also have $[\mathbb{Z}:2\mathbb{Z}]=2$ and more generally $[\mathbb{Z}:n\mathbb{Z}]=n$. In general, the function $f:G\to (G/H)$ which maps an element of $G$ to the coset to which it belongs maps exactly $|H|$ elements of $G$ to each coset.

There are other concepts like this in other fields (@Favst gives a good example from combinatorics), but I'm not aware of a general term that applies across fields of mathematics. If you ever publish a paper that uses this concept, try naming it the Rubinson ratio! Maybe it'll be in a textbook someday.

Comment: "What does this concept do? " That's a good point, and like Favst says and I agree that names, definitions are adopted based on their usage. In fact, I was initially intending to determine the ratio of Cantor subsets of (0,1) to interval subsets  on [$0,1$] (because I am interested in perfect sets), and the point is that, the $k-to-1" correspondence between them (set of Cantor sets and set of intervals), depends on the function between them, which is hardly surprising.

Comment: "I think you're essentially trying to define a way to think about the "size" of one infinite set compared to another". Yes, exactly! Somewhat similar to "natural density" although not using the same procedure that defines natural density. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_density

Comment: @AdamRubinson the correspondence does depend on the function, which is unsurprising, but if there's a few interesting functions that give rise to different structures, topologies, etc., then it might make sense to define the Rubinson ratio. If you find something interesting that the concept does, use it with pride in your paper: it'll either get published or your reviewer will tell you someone else already named it. :)

Comment: I don't have a reviewer: I'm a maths tutor and I sometimes study maths for fun. It arose from my interest in Topology: however, I thought it might have some sort of use in set theory. Or at least, we could extend the idea via set theory first. Which I thought would be a good idea before I use it in exploring some ideas of infinite sets in a topological setting.

Comment: And whilst your answer is more understanding of what I was after, I believe Favst actually answered the question because he provided an acceptable name given to the concept.